# In SQLFORM factory, why is my readonly checkbox field unchecked?

Tags: python, web2py

So this is my controller code:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(Field("something_readonly", writable=False, default="can't change")
                       ,Field("something", requires=IS_LENGTH(10,5))
                       ,Field("some_flag", "boolean", writable=False, default=True))
if form.process().accepted:
    print("validate")

return dict(form=form)
```

When I submit successfully, everything appears how I expect; that is, the "something" field is blank and the read-only fields keep their values.

However, if validation fails (such as submitting without anything in "something"), then **the "some_flag" checkbox is unchecked**. The other read-only field, "something_readonly", keeps its value.

A bug, right? How can I get around this? I can disable the field in javascript in the view, but I would like a solution or workaround that can be done in the controller, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely a bug. As a workaround, after validation fails, you can set the `checked` attribute of the `input` widget to `True`:

```
def fix_booleans(form):
    for fieldname in form.fields:
        field = form.table[fieldname]
        if field.type == 'boolean' and field.writable == False and field.default == True:
            form.custom.widget[fieldname]['_checked'] = True

form.process(onvalidation=dict(onfailure=fix_booleans))
```

Comment: So helpful! Thanks a bunch.